# Configure RedisOutputCacheProvider with Azure Redis DB

Tags: azure, redis, stackexchange.redis

Have web application project (web forms) and Azure subscription. Installed package RedisOutputCacheProvider from Nuget.

Using configuration like suggested:

```
<caching>
      <outputCache defaultProvider="MyRedisOutputCache">
        <providers>
          <!-- Either use 'connectionString' and provide all parameters as string OR use 'host','port','accessKey','ssl','connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds' and 'operationTimeoutInMilliseconds'. -->
          <!-- 'databaseId' and 'applicationName' can be used with both options. -->
          <add name="MyRedisOutputCache" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisOutputCacheProvider"
               host="myhost.redis.cache.windows.net"
               port="6380"
               accessKey="myKey"
               ssl="true"
               connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds = "5000"
               operationTimeoutInMilliseconds = "1000"
               />

        </providers>
      </outputCache>
    </caching>
```

On application start get permanent error: **Can't load type 'Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisOutputCacheProvider'.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. Was conflict between Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisOutputCacheProvider and version of StackExchange.Redis.StrongName library.